# Problems installing KDE in Ubuntu 12.04 xorg problem

Tags: xorg, kubuntu, kde

Hi sorry to bother you guys, I have a problem when I try to install KDE en my Ubuntu 12.04 I go to the terminal and I follow this steps

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

The first two commands work fine, but when I go to the last one I get a message that says

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kubuntu-desktop : Depends: xorg but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What happened? And what is xorg? ..... thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

**xorg**

> :~$ apt-cache show xorg
>
> Description: X.Org X Window System
>
> This metapackage provides the
>   components for a standalone  workstation running the X Window System. 
>   It provides the X libraries, an X  server, a set of fonts, and a group
>   of basic X clients and utilities.
>   .
>   Higher level metapackages, such
>   as those for desktop environments, can  depend on this package and
>   simplify their dependencies.
>   .
>   It should be noted that a package
>   providing x-window-manager should also  be installed to ensure a
>   comfortable X experience.

**Try**

The kubuntu-desktop is depending the xorg. Try to install the xorg. Do you get an error message ?